# More than one image rotations in android simultaneously in a listview. How?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to rotate an image (which is actually a dial with a needle) in a listview. The number of entries in a listview are dynamic. This dial is present in each of the entries. I am able to play the animation on one image, but when i implement it using a for() loop, the app hangs. I need an alternative for the 'for()' loop.

Exactly saying, the rotation is kind of live (like a compass, pointing to my desired location always).

The rotation function which i wrote is as follows. I'm getting the imageviews by using tag-mapping (the image is same for all entries in the listview).

```
private void rotateImageView() {
    Log.d ("","Compass >> >>Rotating..well trying :P>>");
    Log.d ("","USERLIST >>" + imageTags);
    if(imageTags != null)
    {for(HashMap<String, String> map : imageTags)

    {

        View vi = new View(NearUsersList.this);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dir_img);
        if(img != null)
        {
        Log.d ("","IMG IS >>" + img);
        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(
                (float) (-gyroOrientation[0] * 180 / Math.PI + Double.parseDouble(map.get("orientation"))),
                (float) (-gyroOrientation[0] * 180 / Math.PI + Double.parseDouble(map.get("orientation"))),
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        // currentRotation = (currentRotation + 30) % 360;

        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);

        anim.setFillAfter(true);

        img.startAnimation(anim);
           }
    }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that such an implementation would require multi-core processors with huge RAM to run. Such a configuration is certainly unavailable in any of the present android devices. So, figured out another way to achieve it.